# Can I use a variable to apply a condition to multiple sql statements in pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can I write a 'where' statement only once instead of writing it multiple times for each of the sql statements below:

```
select t1.rows as total_var1, t2.rows as total_var2, t3.rows as total_var3
from (
select count(*) as rows from "var1_assessments" where "createdAt" > '2019-09-01' and "createdAt" < '2020-09-01') as t1
cross join (select count(*) as rows from "var2_assessments" where "createdAt" > '2019-09-01' and "createdAt" < '2020-09-01') as t2
cross join (select count(*) as rows from "var3_assessments" where "createdAt" > '2019-09-01' and "createdAt" < '2020-09-01') as t3
```

Comment: Why do you have three tables with nearly the same name? This might indicate a wrong design choice and those three tables should in reality be one table.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I am not sure why you are trying to squeeze the row count of 3 different tables into 1 select statement. It would be a lot cleaner to simply do a row count on each table. It would also be a lot faster too because then the database doesn't need to create this monstrous 3 table cartesian matrix just to get some counts. But, to answer your question, if there are 3 tables involved, there is no way to avoid using 3 different WHERE clauses that I know of.

Comment: How would I write a statement that produces the 3 data points I need without submitting 3 separate sql statements? I'm showing just 3 of the counts that I need, but the reality is that I want to produce 8 different counts and don't want to have to write 8 separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid to write the WHERE clause three times, but if you want to avoid repeating the date range, you can do something like this:

```
with p(range) as (
  values (daterange(date '2019-09-01', date '2020-09-01', '[)')
)  
select *
from (select count(*) as total_var1 from var1_assessments, p where "createdAt" <@ p.range) as t1
  cross join (select count(*) as total_var2 from var2_assessments, p where "createdAt" <@ p.range) as t2
  cross join (select count(*) as total_var3 from var3_assessments, p where "createdAt" <@ p.range) as t3
```